# removing Laucher2 default favorite apps on homescreen

Tags: android, launcher

By default android launcher2 has 3 apps as favorites . they are camera, gallery and settings . Is there anyway I can remove it by making some changes in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have the framework source and building from Android source.
Try playing around with packages/apps/Launcher2/res/xml/default_workspace.xml file, which controls the default applications.